# How to identify (un)successful authentication in Socket.IO (via socketio-auth)?

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io

I'm trying to implement Websocket authentication in a Node.js server with the help of Socket.IO and socketio-auth. My testbed is a simple chat, where the client needs to send a password to the server to get permission to join. I do that via socketio-auth as follows:

Client side:

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('authentication', {client: "client", password: "test"});
});
```

Server side:

```
require('socketio-auth')(io, {authenticate: function(data, cb){
   cb(null, data.password == 'test');} 
})
```

This works as expected. As is, it allows the client to join. If I send the wrong password, the connection gets rejected.

However, I don't know how to collect the data from the server telling the client that it does not have permission to connect. All I get now is a POST on the client console saying '400 Bad request'. How can the client detect it has been denied access?

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to detect the error: Since the server kills the connection, one can simply listen for the 'disconnect' event:

Client:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(error) {
   console.log(error);  // "io server disconnect"
})
```

This of course would fire whenever the socket gets disconnected, for any reason. One way to avoid this is to listen first for the "authenticated" event that gets fired on a successful connection with proper authentication. Inside one simply overrides the 'disconnect' event:

Client:

```
socket.on('authenticated', function() {
   socket.on('disconnect', function(error) {
   // override
   })
})
```